# Is it possible to instantiate a formset which isn't call with {{ formset.as_p }}?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I call a formset but not with `{{ formset.as_p }}`  because I want to change the display of forms.
I know when using `{{ formset.as_p }}`  it is possible to instantiate a field to edit it directly.

But is that possible using a formset that way

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }} {% csrf_token %}
    <table>

      <!-- <br>{{ formset.as_p }}<br> -->

      {% for question in questions %}<hr>

    <label for="question">{{ question }} [{{ question.id }}]</label>  
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-question" value="{{ question.id }}"/>

  </p>    
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Answer :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-answer" placeholder="answer here"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ reply.id }}"/>
    </p>
{% endfor %}

 </table>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    <a href="../../baseVisite/" class="btn btn-success">Retour</a></center>
  </form>
```

I wish I could instantiate the fields answer.

I tried passing in a values like this :

```
{% for reply in question.reply_set.all %}
    <p>
    <label for="answer">Réponse :</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-answer" value="{{ reply.answer }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" name="form-{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}-id" value="{{ reply.id }}"/>
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
```

But by doing it like this just initializes the values and does not allow to modify

**There has a way to do what I wish with this formset structure?**

EDIT :

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, page_id, *args,**kwargs):
        super (ReplyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.filter(page=page_id)

    class Meta:
        model = Reply
        exclude = ('user','creationDate')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to customize the view of a form rendered with a formset. Of course, you can do it, since formset is just a set of forms. Render a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) manually and do so with the [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) as well.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.subject.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
                {{ form.subject }}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.message.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
                {{ form.message }}
            </div>
            # more fields
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

In case you have multiple items field (`question` in your case) in one form you can itterate them and render manually as well:

```
{% for field in form.question %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">Some label:</label> {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want customize my formset as I already do, but what I can not do is complete a pre fields (fields instantiate ) to edit it .. For this time by customizing the formset I can not change a value ... Only to add one

Comment: how can I make him understand that `"id_for_label"` must be the label of each of my questions?

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Have you tried my solution? `id_for_label` option should automatically pass the same `id` as you have for the related `field`. Please show how does your form look like, is it a ModelForm?

Comment: So you've got multiple items in one field. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @chemist I don't want change my structure 
I just wish that instead of adding new values it gets me (if it got one) the values of the response in the db to be able to change later!